# Paper rock scissors game, probably something is missing from my code

Tags: java

I started learning to program in java two/three days ago and decided to try and program a simple rock paper scissors game.
it wont run and i think that i either didn't include some important code or that this whole thing is just garbage.
thanks for help!

```java
    public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String personPlay; //User's play; either R, P or S
        String computerPlay = ""; //Computer's play, R, P or S as well
        int computerInt; //randomly generated number to etermine computers play
        String response;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        
        System.out.prinln("Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n" + "Enter a move: \n" + "R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors");
        
        System.out.println();
        
        computerInt = generator.nextInt(
        
        
        if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay))
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        else if (personPlay.equals("R"))
            if (computerPlay.equals("S"))
                System.out.println("Rock crushes Scissors! You win!");
        else if (personPlay.equals("S"))
            if (computerPlay.equals("P"))
                System.out.println("Scissors cut Paper! You win!");
       else if (personPlay.equals("P"))
            if (computerPlay.equals("R"))
                System.out.println("Paper wraps Rock! You win!");
        else if (personPlay.equals("R"))
            if (computerPlay.equals("P"))
                System.out.println("Paper wraps Rock! You lose!");
         else if (personPlay.equals("P"))
            if (computerPlay.equals("S"))
                System.out.println("Scissors cut Paper! You lose!");
         else if (personPlay.equals("S"))
            if (computerPlay.equals("R"))
                System.out.println("Rock crushes Scissors! You lose!");
        else    System.out.println("Invalid user imput, please try again!");
    }
}
```

Comment: if condition A else if condition A ... do you see how this logic is flawed? You have several of these. You just started. Start at the beginning. No, jumping in the deep end isn't a smart thing to do here. Start using { } blocks on your if statements

Comment: computerInt = generator.nextInt() will give you an int, not R, P or S.
Are you missing some code here?

Comment: If you're nesting if-statements with elses attached to some of them, **use braces** `{}`. Otherwise it's very hard to figure out what will happen. In fact, just always braces. You're not saving yourself any effort by omitting them.

Comment: @Snorik no, computerPlay = "" is in the code. Same for personPlay

Comment: You have a `System.out.prinln` (missing `t`). You are missing the `);` for `computerInt = generator.nextInt(`. As others have pointed out, you are missing the code that gets the string values for the player and for the computer.

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "it won't run": is it a compile error? a runtime error? What error message do you get?

Comment: personPlay is not initialized there so it won't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this answers your question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String personPlay; //User's play; either R, P or S
        String computerPlay = ""; //Computer's play, R, P or S as well
        String response;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n" + "Enter a move: \n" + "R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors");
        System.out.print("Player > ");
        personPlay = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Computer > ");
        String options [] = {"R","P","S"};
        computerPlay = options[(int)(Math.random()*3)];
        System.out.println(computerPlay);
        
        
        if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay)) {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        }
        else if (personPlay.equals("R")) {
            if (computerPlay.equals("P")) {
                System.out.println("Paper wraps Rock! You lose!");
            }
            else if (computerPlay.equals("S")) {
                System.out.println("Rock crushes Scissors! You win!");
            }
        }
        else if (personPlay.equals("P")) {
            if (computerPlay.equals("R")) { 
                System.out.println("Paper wraps Rock! You win!");
            }
            else if (computerPlay.equals("S")) {
                System.out.println("Scissors cut Paper! You lose!");
            }
        }
        else if (personPlay.equals("S")) {
            if (computerPlay.equals("R")) {
                System.out.println("Rock crushes Scissors! You lose!");
            }
            else if (computerPlay.equals("P")) {
                System.out.println("Scissors cut Paper! You win!");
            }
        }
        else { System.out.println("Invalid user imput, please try again!"); }
    }
}
```

There were a few problems with your code, most of them already pointed by other users. I'll only add that the way you wrote those if/else statements, it would never enter some of them.
I don't have much time right now but if you still have any doubts after seeing this answer leave a comment and I'll answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of errors in the code that you have shared :

1. In the statement "System.out.prinln("Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n" + "Enter a move: \n" + "R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors");"
   , it should be System.out.println().You have a spelling-error (missing 't' in 'print')
2. You need to initialize variable 'personPlay' for the code to compile. It is required to initialize local variables as they do not assume a default value.
3. Missing closing bracket for statement :'computerInt = generator.nextInt('.

Fixing these, would let the code compile .
I would suggest using curly braces with each if, else if or else conditions, that would give the code a neat look. Also , there is a long chain of nested if-else conditions which is hard to read and debug(in case of any issue). Try to start with simple conditions and then build your logic in steps , avoiding these many if else conditions.